# How to verify that the password contains X uppercase letters and Y numbers?

Tags: c#, string-matching

How do I verify in C# that the password contains at least X uppercase letters and at least Y numbers, and the entire string is longer than Z?

Thanks.

Comment: I would use some standard pwd validation rules possibly with RegEx, not char by char parsing... see this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152872/creating-a-regex-to-check-for-a-strong-password

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Password Strength:

First, I would read up on password strength, and double-check your policy to make sure you were doing the right thing (I couldn't tell you off hand):

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength
- https://www.grc.com/haystack.htm
- http://xkcd.com/936/ (a joke, but good food for thought)

Then I'd check other questions:

- [Creating a regex to check for a strong password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152872/creating-a-regex-to-check-for-a-strong-password)
- [Password strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014325/password-strength)

Then I'd get down to business.

### Implementation:

You could use Linq:

```
return password.Length >= z
    && password.Where(char.IsUpper).Count() >= x
    && password.Where(char.IsDigit).Count() >= y
    ;
```

You could use also regular expressions (which might be a good option to allow you to plug in more complicated validations in the future):

```
return password.Length >= z
    && new Regex("[A-Z]").Matches(password).Count >= x
    && new Regex("[0-9]").Matches(password).Count >= y
    ;
```

Or you could mix and match them.

If you had to do this multiple times, you could reuse the `Regex` instances by building a class:

```
public class PasswordValidator
{
    public bool IsValid(string password)
    {
        return password.Length > MinimumLength
            && uppercaseCharacterMatcher.Matches(password).Count
                >= FewestUppercaseCharactersAllowed
            && digitsMatcher.Matches(password).Count >= FewestDigitsAllowed
            ;
    }

    public int FewestUppercaseCharactersAllowed { get; set; }
    public int FewestDigitsAllowed { get; set; }
    public int MinimumLength { get; set; }

    private Regex uppercaseCharacterMatcher = new Regex("[A-Z]");
    private Regex digitsMatcher = new Regex("[a-z]");
}

var validator = new PasswordValidator()
{
    FewestUppercaseCharactersAllowed = x,
    FewestDigitsAllowed = y,
    MinimumLength = z,
};

return validator.IsValid(password);
```

Comment: @SaiKalyanAkshinthala: Fixed now.  I saw my mistake while I was expanding my answer :)

Answer (score 7):

To count uppercase letters and digits:

```
string s = "some-password";
int upcaseCount= 0;
int numbersCount= 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    if (char.IsUpper(s[i])) upcaseCount++; 
    if (char.IsDigit(s[i])) numbersCount++;
}
```

and check `s.Length` for the length

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Short and clear using LINQ [Where() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx):

```
int requiredDigits = 5;
int requiredUppercase = 5;
string password = "SomE TrickY PassworD 12345";

bool isValid = password.Where(Char.IsDigit).Count() >= requiredDigits
               && 
               password.Where(Char.IsUpper).Count() >= requiredUppercase;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
public bool CheckPasswordStrength(string password, int x, int y, int z)
{
   return password.Length >= z &&
          password.Count(c => c.IsUpper(c)) >= x &&
          password.Count(c => c.IsDigit(c)) >= y;
}
```