# String Information Class

Tags: c#, .net, string

I am looking for something rather specific, and I don't really know what to call it. Let me explain: I require a small class/struct that takes a string and gathers information about it. So I pass my string into the constructor and it "frisks" the string, gathering how many characters the string has, how many letters are in it, how many numbers, how many lower case letters, how many uppercase letters, how long it is, etc. I was about to develop this myself, but was wondering I it already existed within the .NET framework.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe there is a class/struct that does exactly what you want. However, all the methods necessary to gather the information already exist, and are easy to use.

Comment: .Net does not provide this out of the box. You will need to develop a specific Class to provide this information, or develop a series of String extensions. e.g. NumberCharCount(), UpperCharCount() etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this doesn't exist.  But it's simple enough to write yourself, you can do everything you require with a bit of LINQ and char extensions:

```
var count = str.Count();
var letters = str.Count(char.IsLetter);
var numbers = str.Count(char.IsDigit);
var lowers = str.Count(char.IsLower);
var uppers = str.Count(char.IsUpper);
//etc...
```

Comment: Simple enough if one does not care about surrogate pairs and all kind of combining characters... For more serious code [TextElementEnumerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textelementenumerator(v=vs.110).aspx) may be needed.

Answer (score 2):

**NO** there is no such class exists in .NET Framework which gives you all the necessary details you are looking for. You need to create it yourself.

Just my assumption after looking at the details you are looking into the string you might be looking for [Verifying Password Strength](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8414591/3796048)

Comment: Not exactly, but you were pretty close to what I am needing this for. Good guess!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Char](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Char(v=vs.110).aspx) structure.
It has lots of static functions like `Char.IsDigit`, `Char.IsNumber`, `Char.IsLower`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the System.String and System.Char classes to gather information, you can use classes in the [System.Globalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace, such as StringInfo, TextInfo, CharUnicodeInfo and others.

Moreover, you can use the [Character Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in Regular Expressions. For example, Unicode [Categories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories): diacritic marks, punctuation and others. Or Unicode Named [Blocks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#SupportedNamedBlocks): IsGreek, IsCyrillic and many others.